# cellForRowAtIndexPath Not Calling after any change in core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am saving the data using context and my `FetchedResultsController` listens to changes:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{
    NSLog(@"CHECK THE COUNT AND INDEXPATH %d , %d ",[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count],indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"New Indexpath %d",newIndexPath.row);
    if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; //UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic
    } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeMove) {
        [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate) {
//        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }  else {
        NSAssert(NO,@"");
    }
}
```

This Delegate is getting called, but after that, the `TableView` which is binded to the fetchedResultsController is not getting updated with the latest record inserted.

Comment: have you checked `self.tableView` for `nil`?

Comment: could you show some more code, `numberOfRowsInSection` for instance?

Comment: Is it just that the index path is for a section of the table which isn't currently on display?

Comment: Yes I can see all other rows , except the freshly inserted records

Comment: Why are you doing a chain of if statements here instead of a switch?  The Apple provided code is very good and a switch is going to be faster than this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you implement all of the delegate methods for the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`?  Sounds like you have turned off updating in the `-controllerWillChangeContent:` but didn't turn it back on by implementing the `-controllerDidChangeContent:` method properly.

If you have them both implemented then please update your question with that code as well.

Comment: Yes i implemented that before                                        its working fine now    I believe the issue was because corrupted data fetched by fetchresultsController           Thank you all for your clarifications..

Comment: Then you need to update your question and show them. Showing the code that works isn't nearly as helpful as the code that is probably not working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions Marcus , will do that